# Using Variables[] as the argument of Plot[]

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

I want to use the `Variables[]` function to extract the name of the variable of a function, such that I can use it later, e.g. in a `Plot[]` function.

The following *Mathematica* code provides a minimal working example:

```
f=x+x^2
Variables[f]
Plot[f,{x,-2,2}]
Plot[f,{Variables[f],-2,2}]
```

Please note that I am aware there are better ways to define functions, such as `f[x_]:=x+x^2`. I also know I could use a `Rule[]` applied to `f` to define a new dummy variable within the `Plot[]` function. That is *not* the point.

The example I provided is simply a short piece of code to test the way `Variables[]` works. My question concerns the function `Variables[]`, what it returns and how it can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables) returns a list, not a symbol, so you need to extract the symbol. Also, [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll), so you need to circumvent that:

```
Plot[f, Evaluate @ {First@Variables[f], -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Or:

```
With[{v = First @ Variables[f]}, Plot[f, {v, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated. I had actually already tried `First[]` and `Evaluate[]` in the following manner: `Plot[f, {Evaluate[First[Variables[f]]], -2, 2}]`. That does *not* work. Your way does. +1

Comment: While we're at it, any suggestion for dealing with the possibility of `Variables[]` returning a list of 2 elements `{x, y}`? I could put an `If[]` around it and use `Plot[]` in one case and `Plot3D[]` in the other, but that's not elegant.

Comment: @LBogaardt If you define `plot = {Plot, Plot3D}[[Length[#3]]][#, Evaluate[Sequence @@ (#2 /@ #3)]] &;` then call `plot[f, {#, -2, 2} &, Variables[f]]`