# Using List of Variables to construct Control[] within Manipulate[]

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, gui-construction, symbols

How can I use a list of variable names within `Symbol[]` inside a `Manipulate[]`, specifically using `Control[]`?

I assume the problem arises due to the `HoldAll` attribute of `Manipulate`, similar to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171060/using-variables-as-the-argument-of-plot), but I fail to find the right solution.

The following *Mathematica* code illustrates the problem:

```
myVariables={"var1","var2"}
Map[Symbol[#]&,myVariables]
Manipulate[Map[Symbol[#]&,myVariables],Grid[{{Control[{var1,0,1}],Control[{var2,0,1}]}}]]
Map[Control[{Symbol[#],0,1}]&,myVariables]
Manipulate[Map[Symbol[#]&,myVariables],Grid[{Map[Control[{Symbol[#],0,1}]&, myVariables]}]]
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `Symbol`? It is designed to convert strings to symbols. Also, take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/manipulate-with-a-variable-number-of-sliders), something similar should work for you

Comment: @Mathe172 I want the Symbols (or their names) used inside the Manipulate to be pre-defined in some List. I do not see anything useful in your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `vList` be your list of variables:

```
vList = {var1, var2};
```

*(I don't see any reason to define the list using strings, but if you insist you could do `vList = Symbol /@ {"var1", "var2"}`)*. Then, you need to use `With` to inject things into a HoldAll object like Manipulate, so one possibility is:

```
With[{v=vList, controls = Grid[{Control[{#, 0, 1}]& /@ vList}]},
    Manipulate[v, controls]
]
```

[image]